# ¿Como validar formulario de editar si tengo campos únicos?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-8

verán tengo mi formulario de editar clientes y le agregue validaciones con ajax, el RFC es campo único por lo cual mi intención fue que al editar no registraran un cliente que ya existe. Mi validación funciona al editar solo el primer registro de mi tabla , si quiero editar algún otro cliente ya no funciona, tampoco me agarra las funciones para convertir texto a mayusculas.

> Este es mi formulario (solo deje el campo de RFC que es el que estoy validando)

```html
<!-- COMIENZA MODAL EDITAR CLIENTE -->
<form action="{{ route('admin.clientes.update', $c->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf @method('PUT')
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade modalEditar" name="myModalE" id="myModalE{{ $c->id }}" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Editar cliente') }}</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-row" id="grupo__rfcEditar">
            <div class="form-group col formulario__grupo">
              <input type="text" id="idClienteEditar" name="idClienteEditar" value="{{ $c->id }}" hidden>
              <strong>{{ __('RFC') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" name="rfcEditar" id="rfcEditar" value="{{ $c->RFC }}" maxlength="14" minlength="10">
              <div id="respuestaRFCEditar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- TERMINA MODAL EDITAR CLIENTE -->
```

> Aqui mi javaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#rfcEditar").on("keypress", function() {
    $input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $input.val($input.val().toUpperCase());
    }, 50);
  })

  $("#rfcEditar").bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  })

});

$('#rfcEditar').on('keyup', function() {

  var rfc = $('#rfcEditar').val();
  var longitudRFC = $('#rfcEditar').val().length;
  var idRFCEditar = $('#idClienteEditar').val();

  console.log(rfc);
  //console.log(idRFCEditar);

  if (longitudRFC === 0) {


    $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);
  }

  if (longitudRFC < 10) {
    $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("<strong style='color: red'>El rfc debe contener entre 10 y 14 caracteres</strong>");
    document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');

    $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', true);
    $('.btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', true);


  }

  //console.log(longitudRFC);
  else if (longitudRFC >= 10 || longitudRFC <= 14) {

    var a = 'rfc=' + rfc;
    var idRFCEditarE = $('#idClienteEditar').val();

    // console.log(a);
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    var url = '{{ url('
    validarRFCEditar ') }}';

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        idRFCEditarE,
        rfc
      },
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == 0) {

          console.log('Entre a opcion 0 ya existe en el propio registro');

          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("");
          document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
          document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto');
          //  $('#respuestaRFCEditar').html(response.message)
          $('.btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);

        } else if (response.success == 1) {

          console.log('Entre a opcion 1 no cumple condicion');
          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("");
          $('#respuestaRFCEditar').html(response.message);
          document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto');
          document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
          $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', true);

        } else if (response.success == 2) {

          console.log('Entre a opcion 2 disponible para cambio');

          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("");
          document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
          document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto');
          $('#respuestaRFCEditar').html(response.message)
          $('.btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', false);

          $('#razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('#telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);

        }

      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });


  }

});
```

> Y mi controlador

```
public function ajaxRequestPostRFCEditar(Request $request)
{

$jsonData = array();

$RFC = $request->rfc;
$idRFC = $request->idRFCEditarE;

// Da 1 si encuentra coincidencia
// Da 0 si no encuentra coincidencias

$buscarRFC =  cliente::select('id','RFC','razonSocial') 
->where([
    ['id', '=', $idRFC],
    ['RFC','=', $RFC]
])
->get();

$buscarRFC2 = cliente::select('RFC','razonSocial')
        ->where('RFC','=', $RFC)
        ->get();


$existeRFC = count($buscarRFC);

  $existeRFC2 = count($buscarRFC2);

if($existeRFC > 0 && $existeRFC2 > 0){

        $jsonData['success'] = 0;

      $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: green;">RFC ('.$RFC.')</strong></p>';

    }else if($existeRFC <= 0 && $existeRFC2 > 0){

         $jsonData['success'] = 1;

       $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: red;">El RFC ('.$RFC.') ya existe para otro registro</strong> </p>';

    }else if($existeRFC <= 0 && $existeRFC2 <= 0){

        $jsonData['success'] = 2;

       $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: green;">RFC ('.$RFC.') disponible</strong></p>';

    }

    return response()->json(
        [
            'success' =>  $jsonData['success'],
            'message' =>  $jsonData['message']
        ]
    );
```

}

Me funciona tal como quería con el primer registro de mi tabla, con los demás ya no:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/831hebdnh0l3ja5/Screen%20Recording%2027-4-2023%20at%2009.49.mp4?dl=0